# Remove jquery UI CDN from Wordpress Admin panel

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, cdn

I'm install wordpress on localhost for using offline works.

But I have a problem, on offline mode exist jquery ui cdn from http://code.jquery.com in admin panel (wp-admin).

that causes admin panel loading slowly and try to connect to jquery.com

[image]

I want to know, how to remove this CDN from admin panel ??

thanks.

Comment: deactivate all plugins. if that script dissapeared, then it caused by some plugin. if not, then it rendered by theme. so, dig into theme files. if it dissapeared after deactivating plugins, then switch on plugins one-by-one and after activating one of them, look at page rendered scripts. this way you should find where its comming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that stylesheet with CDN link was added by the theme or a plugin that you are using. You need to find it in the code, and replace the CDN link with the location of the local copy of it(hope you've already downloaded it).

For that, you need to figure out exactly where that line is in the code. If its added by the theme, maybe look for the `header.php` file (if its hardcoded) or maybe look at the `functions.php` file. It might be added through the function [wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Hope it helps!